# Natural Scrolling doesn't work in 12.04 in some windows. Where should I report the bug?

Tags: 12.04, bug-reporting, mouse-scroll

Natural scrolling using ".Xmodmap": `pointer = 1 2 3 5 4 7 6 8 9 10 11 12` doesn't work anymore in 12.04 on some Ubuntu-specific apps like the Software Center, settings window, and update-center. Under what package should I report the bug?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm horribly late to this, but I just finished writing [a guide](http://andym3.wordpress.com/2012/05/27/fixing-natural-scrolling-in-ubuntu-12-04/) which could help you or anyone passing by. If you still have this problem, that is.

The gist of it is that you need to get your touchpad's ID with the `xinput list` command, then the current scrolling distance with `xinput list-props [touchpad-id] | grep "Scrolling distance"`. The output should be something like:

`Synaptics Scrolling Distance (288):    106, 106`

Here, `288` is the property ID and `106, 106` are the current values. What you need to do is invert the numbers - here, the new values will be `-106, -106`. This command does it:

`xinput set-prop [touchpad-id] [property-id] [new-values]`

I have this in a shell script set to run on login, along with commands to restart nautilus, which may or may not work for you (it's in the linked blog post).

Comment: That's great. It actually fixed the problem for me! Thanks so much!

Comment: Works for me as well. But note that you have to turn of the Natural Scrolling application afterwards. Otherwise the behavior in all windows is just inverted :)

Comment: @Andy C. is there a way to do the same for my mouse?

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks! I used several ways on 15.04 including Ubuntu Tweak's Natural Scrolling and they all only worked for some cases but not all. This finally seems to be a OS version independent solution.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose the best way to do this is by using dconf-editor:

- Open Terminal
- Type in *dconf-editor* and hit Enter
- Now go to **org>gnome>settings-daemon>peripherals>touchpad** and uncheck **natural scroll**

You may need to install dconf-editor first, by executing `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor` in the terminal.

This will only reverse the scroll direction of the touchpad, not of an external mouse.

Here's a screenshot of dconf-editor after making changes:

[image]

Comment: Hang on, since when has this existed?

Comment: I have used Ubuntu 12.04+ mainly, and it has been there in each and every version.

Comment: Strange, I use 12.04 with the latest updates and this option is missing.

Comment: If it ain't there, try `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`

Answer (score 1):

[Bug #949465](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libxi/+bug/949465) is a similar-sounding duplicate which was reported for natural scrolling in Nautilus. It's filed against the `libxi` package, so you may want to try filing it there.

Either that, or may want to try filing bugs against the packages for all affected windows. For example, the packages for the software you have listed above would be:

- Ubuntu Software Center: `software-center`
- System Settings: `gnome-control-center`
- Update Manager: `update-manager`

You can report bugs against any of these by running `ubuntu-bug` in a terminal, followed by the name of the desired package.