# Natural scrolling with mouse on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mouse, scrolling

I'm trying to figure out a way to get natural (reverse) scrolling to work with a mouse. I know Ubuntu has a "natural scrolling" preference under System Settings, however, that only applies to the trackpad and doesn't work with an external mouse. I've tried the ["naturalscrolling" package from ppa:zedtux/naturalscrolling](https://launchpad.net/~zedtux/+archive/ubuntu/naturalscrolling):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:zedtux/naturalscrolling
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install naturalscrolling
```

I also tried messing with the `.Xmodmap` file; however, that doesn't seem to work consistently across all applications, which drives me crazy.

Anyone knows how to get natural scrolling to work consistently across all applications with a mouse?

Comment: The natural scrolling is "natural" for touchpad because on touchpad, it is a sliding action. But, with a mouse wheel, because the wheel does a rolling action, reverse scrolling is natural. Think of the screen as a paper placed on a tabletop and imagine the 2 movements - sliding the paper with fingers and moving it with a fixed roller.

Comment: I understand the analogies, but ultimately there's no correct or incorrect way to implement scrolling -- it's just a matter of preference. Just like some people prefer traditional scrolling even on a trackpad, I prefer reverse scrolling even when using a mouse.

Comment: I like the  "naturalscrolling" package from ppa:zedtux/naturalscrolling, it works fine for me. Which apps don't work with the ppa?

Comment: The "natural scrolling" package doesn't work with Files, Rhythmbox, gedit, Software updater, and Ubuntu software center. I'm sure there are others also. I think it has something to do with those apps implementing the new GTK smooth scrolling.

Comment: The solution I've posted for [Reverse two finger scroll direction?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91426/reverse-two-finger-scroll-direction/278849#278849) should also work for mouse. Direct [link to my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/278849/147496).