# Natural Scrolling on Ubuntu Gnome isn't working

Tags: gnome, mouse, touchpad, mouse-scroll, scrolling

I have what is (as far as I can remember) a vanilla Ubuntu installation (v.14.10) using the Gnome Desktop (v.3.9.90), yet I can't seem to get reverse scrolling to work.

There's no option for natural scrolling the basic Gnome mouse configuration or in the Gnome tweak tool.  But in `dconf` there is an option under:

```
org/gnome/settings-daemon/periferals/touchpad[natural-scroll]: 'checked'
```

But this has no effect for me.  I've tried several techniques including the ones suggested in the attached issues, with no luck.

[How to enable natural scroll on two-finger scroll with command while normal scrolling for edge scrolling in Ubuntu 13.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/373147/how-to-enable-natural-scroll-on-two-finger-scroll-with-command-while-normal-scro)

[Natural scrolling with mouse on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496205/natural-scrolling-with-mouse-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: I had the same issue in a "normal" Ubuntu installation after moving from Unity to Gnome. Natural Scrolling is now working in Gnome thanks to [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/907847/270625)

Comment: You can consider [my answer on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/707365/318461) - is it suitable to be posted here? No need for any uninstalling there. [This U&L Q/A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/307928/318461) could also be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [solution linked in the comment](https://askubuntu.com/a/907847/270625), uninstall `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`

```
sudo purge xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

then log out and back in.