# How to enable natural scrolling on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04

Tags: touchpad, ubuntu-gnome, scrolling

I have just installed ubuntu-gnome-16.04 flavor on my notebook and am quite pleased with it.

But natural scrolling was not really working. I have followed some answers on these questions:

1. [Enable natural scrolling on ubuntu 17.04 with gnome-shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907279/enable-natural-scrolling-on-ubuntu-17-04-with-gnome-shell)
2. [Reverse two finger scroll direction (natural scrolling)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91426/reverse-two-finger-scroll-direction-natural-scrolling)
3. [How to enable natural scrolling with mouse in 17.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904684/how-to-enable-natural-scrolling-with-mouse-in-17-04)

After installing `xserver-xorg-input-libinput`, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/907505/293349) in particular gave me what I wanted, but only until I reboot. How can I make this permanent?

Why this is not a duplicate:
I am not looking for a way to run this command every time I boot ubuntu. I am looking for a proper way of change the settings without the need to run this command arbitrarily every time I boot. Specially, I am trying to avoid putting this command to change a setting anywhere it doesn't belong. I had previously managed to make it work by making the command run on by appending it to `~/.bashrc`. But leaving it there felt unnatural. Maybe I am wrong, but I have the feeling this is not the proper place to make this setting change even if it does work

Comment: @Fabby This is not really a duplicate as the intent is not to run applications on login. I don't know if commands count as applications, but my intention was to alter an option somewhere to make a simple change in configurations permanent. I feel these are different matters, albeit with similar answers

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/949323/restore-natural-scrolling-in-ubuntu-16-04-on-dell-xps-13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I did and it works for me is to add the line

```
xinput set-prop 10 278 1
```

into the .bashrc file.

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

Thanks for sharing the answer, i found your question while I was searching how to make my mouse with a Natural Scroll

Comment: I initially applied the same fix, don't know if you saw my comment on this thread that was removed due to the duplicate flagging. Curiously, after this whole ordeal, the option to activate natural scrolling apeared in my touchpad settings. Since, I have undone the .bashrc fix and things have just been wroking fine

Comment: I got this error  " property '278' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format"

Comment: This link helped me https://www.maketecheasier.com/reverse-mouse-scrolling-direction-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Yes, the answer is not correct for all cases, because the id of the mouse and natural scrolling property may differ for different users

Comment: You can find the actual IDs with 'xinput list' for the mouse and 'xinput list-props _mouseid'  where _mouseid is the id of your mouse.

Comment: The last command I use for natural scrolling is 'gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse natural-scroll true'