# Restore natural scrolling in Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell XPS 13

Tags: touchpad, dell, scrolling

I have a Dell XPS 13 which, by default, has a very sensitive trackpad. As you are typing, if you brush the trackpad by accident, the trackpad considers it as a click and the text insertion point jumps to wherever the mouse happens to be. I found and installed [this fix](https://medium.com/@patrickmmartin/dell-xps-13-9360-journey-to-linux-trackpad-fix-a2d9b551d291) for this issue:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-libinput
```

However, now the scrolling is unnatural. When I use the trackpad to scroll a long document, it is the viewport that moves over the content. I want the content to move in the same direction as my fingers, just as it did before, just like on a touchscreen.

Can you explain to me what changes I should make to the files at `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` that will make this happen?

The solution proposed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/519859/426741) did not help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse two finger scroll direction (natural scrolling)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91426/reverse-two-finger-scroll-direction-natural-scrolling)

Comment: This is wrong for `libinput`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit the file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf` or `90-libinput.conf` depending on your HWE stack.

Add to the end of the touchpad section of the file a line

```
Option "NaturalScrolling" "True"
```

and restart the session.

The section should look this way:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
        Option "NaturalScrolling" "True"
EndSection
```

You can also add `Option "Tapping" "True"`, if you want to enable tap to click feature.

Comment: OP has added some specific information about how they applied your solution in a separate answer below. Would you mind including those details into your post, so that the other one can be tidied up?

Comment: OK. I am adding the example. I was going to add it myself, but I was not behind a laptop with libinput at that time.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone prefers not to restart their X server you can do this with `xinput`.

1. Run `xinput --list`
2. Note the identifier of your trackpad
3. Run `xinput --list-props <trackpad identifier>`
4. Note the identifier of the natural scrolling parameter
5. Run `xinput --set-prop <trackpad identifier> <natural scrolling parameter> 1`

For example, on my system I run

```
xinput --set-prop "CUST0001:00 06CB:76B1 Touchpad" "libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled" 1
```