# Restore tap to click in Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell XPS 13

Tags: touchpad, dell, tap-to-click

This question follows on from [this one about natural scrolling](https://askubuntu.com/q/949323/426741).

Before I made changes, I could simply tap on the trackpad of my Dell XPS 13 to generate a click. Now I have to explicitly click, which requires extra effort. I would like to restore tap-to-click if that is possible.

I have a Dell XPS 13 which, by default, has a very sensitive trackpad. As you are typing, if you brush the trackpad by accident, the trackpad considers it as a click and the text insertion point jumps to wherever the mouse happens to be. I found and installed [this fix](https://askubuntu.com/q/949323/426741) for this issue:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-libinput
```

This inverted the scrolling direction, so I also edited the entry for `MatchIsTouchpad` in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-libinput.conf`:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
        Option "NaturalScrolling" "true"
EndSection
```

With this new setup, tap-to-click does not happen. Is this inevitable? Is this the only way to prevent accidentally brushing the trackpad from generating a click? Or is it possible to regulate the sensitivity so that a deliberate tap is treated differently from a fleeting touch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding...

```
    Option "Tapping" "True"
```

... to the entry for `MatchIsTouchpad` does the trick.