# To reverse the default functioning of touch pad

Tags: 14.04, touchpad

I am used to use the touch pad from down-to-top, not from down-to-down when scrolling any page.

How can you reverse the functioning of the touchpad in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it up in

System Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad -> Natural Scrolling.

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to change this in terminal so I can automate this change for future builds?

Comment: @Masi What do you mean by "builds"? Installs? On the same laptop?

Comment: Just some config file which I could export to future installs.

Comment: Look here http://askubuntu.com/a/519859/167850