# Inconsistent mouse and touchpad scroll behaviour across applications

Tags: unity, 15.04, mouse, touchpad, scrolling

The mouse/touchpad scrolling behaviour on ubuntu 15.04 appears to be inconsistent. Compared to the ***"Mouse and TouchPad"*** settings, the few applications I have tried group like this:

- same as setting: (chrome, emacs, firefox)
- opposite to setting: (gedit, gnome-terminal)

I don't remember seeing this behaviour in 14.04. Does anyone know how to make the scrolling behaviour consistent across all applications?

System Info:

```
$ uname -a
Linux Ideapad-Z570 3.19.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 11 14:16:45 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced the same issue. You can use below procedure to fix it. This will apply system-wide uniform scrolling.

1. On Terminal write: `xev -event mouse`. You will get one small box and when you bring your mouse into that section you will get a lot data getting generated into the Terminal.
2. On scrolling up, note the button name, lets say "x" (in my case it is button 5). Also note down the button name on scrolling down, lets say "y". in my case it is "4".
3. Create a backup of `~/.Xmodmap` file by using `cp ~/.Xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap.bak`.
4. Do `cat ~/.Xmodmap`. Output would be like `pointer = 1 2 3 5 4 6 7 8 9 10 11 12`
5. In the above output search for x and y and they will be in consecutive position and just swap them.
   In my case `echo "pointer = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12" > ~/.Xmodmap && xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` worked. Note switch of `4` and `5`.
6. Now the scrolling will be applied system wide. No need to reboot.

Note: You must undo all the modifications you have made before applying this setting.

Comment: I found that this does not work for my mouse on 15.10. However the **Alternate Method** of [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/519859/32377) did the trick.

Comment: With the release of 16.04 the *Alternate Method* in the [linked answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/519859/32377) does not work any more (probably because the `Driver "mouse"` does not exist). However the recommended method does work. I can not comment there so I am making a note here.