# How do I fix my track pad scroll direction?

Tags: unity, mouse, touchpad, multi-touch, scrolling

That is, without changing my mouse wheel's scroll direction?

The two are off, IMO.  I prefer the MacOsX approach, but anything that makes them consistent would be better than what I have now.

This question: [Reverse two finger scroll direction (natural scrolling)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91426/reverse-two-finger-scroll-direction-natural-scrolling) seems to address a similar concern but the solutions all appear to reverse the directions globally, that is, for all pointer devices, rather than on a per pointer device basis.

How do I set this on a per pointer device basis?

Comment: 14.04 natural scrolling does not affect my mouse wheel, just the two finger touchpad.

Comment: the second answer seems like what  you want .. that should change it for synaptics touchpad but shouldn't effect a connected mouse