# vertical scroll issue on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mouse, touchpad

I run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (64 bit). My laptop is a HP-Pavilion DV3 NoteBook  with a Core2Duo processor.

Before I had Ubuntu 12.04 32bit and vertical scroll on my laptop mouse pad was working perfectly fine. Now I moved to Ubuntu 16.04 and that vertical scroll is not working in it. (cursor is working perfectly fine though)

I also enabled "natural scrolling-on" on **System Settings > Mouse and TouchPad**. This did not fix it.

I tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/929178/420786) to [How to enable natural scrolling with mouse in 17.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904684/how-to-enable-natural-scrolling-with-mouse-in-17-04)
But I'm not able to save as notification arises on editor that I do not have permissions to save on respective location.

How do I fix vertical scrolling?

Comment: try opening the editor with sudo ex. `sudo nano`

Comment: What does the second last paragraph have in common with the question?

Comment: "it describe one of the solutions that  i tried after searching on internet",,but it doesn't work...so i mentioned here so as to save time of users posting answers @ubashu

Comment: @rc49 Oh so you mean you tried this but you can't save the settings?

Comment: @ubashu yes but this resolves using sudo nano as posted by "ravery" but this too doesnt work!!! m not able to find solution!!! My os is up-to-date too

Comment: @ravery this doesnt work ..though m able to save settings using sudo nano but still facing same problem!!!