# 20.04 Natural scrolling not persisting between sessions

Tags: gnome, 20.04, reboot, scrolling

Since updating, natural scrolling works just fine - up until reboot. Toggling the setting off and on again does the trick, but is rather... Annoying.

Grateful for any advice!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scroll direction keeps changing after recent upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286559/scroll-direction-keeps-changing-after-recent-upgrade)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've noticed the same; it's really annoying. Mine also "forgets" the setting I have for Caps Lock (make it an Esc), which drives me crazy.

The following two terminal commands will fix things

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse natural-scroll true`

And for my escape problem:
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['caps:escape']"`

(edit2) Since I've turned the settings off and on again in the terminal, they haven't magically disappeared. Maybe it's enough to just run the below once? (turn it off and on again :) )

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse natural-scroll false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse natural-scroll true
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, cheers!

Comment: In case somebody else wonders about this, you can find other xkb-options by doing something like: `grep -E "(ctrl|caps):" /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst`

Comment: Yep, this helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

*edit:*

I just found a [better solution / workaround](https://askubuntu.com/a/929178/685777) to my original answer:

Add `Option "NaturalScrolling" "on"` to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`

In context:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput pointer catchall"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Option "NaturalScrolling" "on"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection
```

Then restart the X session (i.e.: log out or restart)

Comment: I have a wireless / bluetooth mouse. Natural scrolling setting is ignored everytime I disconnect and reconnect my mouse. Although it is activated in Gnome Control Center, I have to switch it off and on again to make it work. The strange thing is, I have two laptopts (Dell & HP) with Ubuntu 20.04; HP works fine, Dell has this annoying bug. No idea what else to check or do

Comment: @Mariano'AcidWndsurf' thanks for you insight. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Excellent! It worked perfectly. Thank you very much!