# Natural scrolling setting get reset

Tags: 20.04, mouse, bluetooth, system-settings, scrolling

I'm using bluetooth mouse A4Tech BT-630 in Ubuntu 20.04. Each time I go afk the mouse goes to sleep and when I click any mouse button to wake it up the natural scrolling setting I've set previously is not restored.

Interestingly that the switch is still "on" in the System Settings app but the scrolling is reverse to natural in all windows.
In order to fix this I have to switch natural scrolling setting to "off" and then back to "on" in the System Settings app. That only helps until the next time mouse goes to sleep.

The solution [described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1282097/20-04-natural-scrolling-not-persisting-between-sessions) didn't help in my case. I hope someone have other ideas which may help me to overcome the issue.

Comment: Add `Option "NaturalScrolling" "on"` to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`. See details: https://askubuntu.com/a/1283546/685777

Comment: Using gsettings to turn it off and on again as described in the linked post did not make the setting persistent between sessions.

Comment: @skiss That solved the issue for me, but started to work only after I've restarted my machine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This started happening for me too at about the start of October, having used 20.04 and a BT mouse since 20.04's release. Just noting that in case we can triage what changed around that point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [20.04 Natural scrolling not persisting between sessions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1282097/20-04-natural-scrolling-not-persisting-between-sessions)

Comment: No. Still not persistent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scroll direction keeps changing after recent upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286559/scroll-direction-keeps-changing-after-recent-upgrade)

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal:

```
sudo vi /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf
```

Using the arrow key, go down to one line after the one reading *Identifier "libinput pointer catchall".*

Press <kbd>i</kbd> for Insert. Then type or paste:

```
Option "NaturalScrolling" "on"
```

Then press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to exit edit mode, <kbd>:</kbd> for the menu, and then <kbd>w</kbd> to save the file and then <kbd>q</kbd> to quit.

To restart X without rebooting:

```
sudo service gdm3 restart
```

For details see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1283546/685777