# Scroll direction keeps changing after recent upgrade

Tags: mouse, scrolling, mouse-scroll

After a recent kernel upgrade, I started noticing an annoying issue: the "Natural scroll direction" changes every time I change the keyboard/mouse set on my laptop (Dell Inspiron 15).  More specifically, I have one Logitech set at work and a different set (also Logitech) at home.  It seems as though every time I switch peripherals the scroll direction is changed.  I want the Natural Scrolling to be left by default and not arbitrarily switch to the 'regular' scrolling direction.

I believe this may have started after the update to the 5.4.0-52 64-bit kernel (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, GNOME version 3.36.3).  I should note that around the same time I purchased a new set of keyboard/mouse combination for home, though I did not notice the issue until the kernel update a few days later.

What is worse, the toggle button in the Settings > Mouse & Touchpad > Mouse > Natural Scrolling is NOT changed but the scrolling direction changes.  That is, when I just change locations, the scrolling direction is 'regular' while the Natural Scrolling is turned on.  To fix this, all I have to do is to toggle the button twice and then it comes back to my preferred scrolling direction.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?  If so, any way you suggest to fix it without having to change the direction every time I change peripherals.

Comment: Same issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286986/natural-scrolling-not-preserved-after-unplugging-mouse/

Comment: I have the same problem with Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell XPS.

Comment: As of the latest kernel upgrade (Jan. 2021), this matter has now been resolved.  Tested several times and it is working fine.

Comment: Now got it on Xubuntu as of 2021/11/10!  Had it once before and had to get in into all sorts of Cron nonesense, resetting it all the time.
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: If the problem still persists, you could write a script that reverts this change every time it happens like in [my answer  on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/707365/318461). Is that needed?

Comment: This is no longer an issue, not for me at least.  Thank you  @Cadoiz though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue is currently being tracked on the Pop!_OS github here: https://github.com/pop-os/gnome-control-center/issues/120

And on the GNOME/mutter gitlab here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1505

Apologies for writing as an answer, but I can't comment currently.

The bug has been identified and a fix has been [applied](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/merge_requests/1553). The current planned release is Nov 21, but could possibly happen sooner. It appears to be backported to 3.36 and 3.38 as well.

Comment: Thanks @Cameron for bringing this up.

Comment: @JuanAntonio If you can, please like / star the issue and add your report to the GNOME issue as that seems to have the highest probability of inciting a fix.

Comment: done!  Not too many people raising the issue though.  Hope it will be addressed soon.  It is kind of annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a work around for this problem. surface pro 6 recent install of ubuntu 20.10/gnome. Go to Gnome tweak tools>keyboard and mouse. towards the bottom under "touchpad" there's an option to "disable touchpad while typing". make sure that's turned off. I did a restart, not sure if its need though.