# Natural Scrolling Not Preserved After Unplugging Mouse

Tags: 20.04, mouse

I use "natural scrolling" on my mouse, and in the last few days I've found that after unplugging my mouse and then plugging it back in, those settings are reverted. In order to return to using natural scrolling I must first turn off the setting (because the settings display shows it's still on) and then turn if back on again. Restarting the computer while the mouse is plugged in will also return scrolling to its intended setting.

Any help regarding this is much appreciated.

- Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- GNOME version 3.36.3
- Not really sure what other version info is relevant here.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286559/scroll-direction-keeps-changing-after-recent-upgrade?rq=1

Comment: @Morshea: given that the other post came earlier, and that it seems to have a bit more information, I suggest this one being removed.  I will leave it to you though.

Comment: @JuanAntonio I tend to think deleting valid question isn't really the right way to go. I do wish I could flag this as a duplicate and point to yours, but can't because it's still unanswered. I'll try remember to flag as duplicate if yours get an answer first though.

Comment: Copying here a comment from @Cameron in the other thread:
This issue is currently being tracked on the Pop!_OS [GitHub here](https://github.com/pop-os/gnome-control-center/issues/120).

And on the GNOME/mutter [GitLab here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1505).

Comment: I recommend you like / start the bug reports cited above.  Apparently, this is how one can raise the issue.

Comment: @JuanAntonio Flagged this as duplicate now.

Comment: As of the latest kernel upgrade (Jan. 2021), this matter has now been resolved.  Tested several times and it is working fine.