# Losing natural scrolling after wake

Tags: 20.04, mouse, bluetooth, scrolling

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.
When the PC wakes, the natural scrolling options of my Bluetooth mouse, event checked, don't work. I need to uncheck and check again the option.
Can I do anything to solve this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. If you're using Gnome, looks like it's being tracked here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1505 Make sure you upvote that issue if it matches what you're experiencing. There's also an open question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286559/scroll-direction-keeps-changing-after-recent-upgrade/1289665#1289665