# Mouse Setting Won't Save - Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: mouse, settings

I just updated to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and the mouse settings obviously re-set to the defaults where the left button is the primary. I mouse left handed and want the right button to be the primary. I open Settings>Mouse & Touchpad, select Right as Primary Button and all is good. When I KVM over to another system and come back to Ubuntu, the default mouse setting are back.

Please help me get this setting to stick.

Comment: The mouse settings should stick, but I am thinking that every time you KVM and switch back it detects it like a new mouse again.  Try running `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse left-handed true` and see if that sticks that way.

Comment: I've noticed it occurring when I switch monitors inputs. The settings still appear correct, but are not taking effect. Toggle, off and back on for inverse scroll and that works. Will try gsettings. Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue and it appears to be answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286559/scroll-direction-keeps-changing-after-recent-upgrade) already!