# Reverse two-finger scroll gesture not working in menu

Tags: xorg, touchpad, dell, synaptics, scrolling

I am on a Dell Inspiron 15 3000 series running Zorin OS 12.2 (I know this forum is for Ubuntu, but it is based on Ubuntu 16.04.2, and I am pretty sure this issue will be the same on either OS).

I want to reverse the direction of two-finger scrolling. (So dragging two fingers down makes the scrollbar go down.)
I looked at several questions already, including [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91426/reverse-two-finger-scroll-direction-natural-scrolling) one, but none helped me.

Output of `xinput list` command (excluding keyboard info):

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL0651:00 06CB:2985                      id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

I know my touchpad is the third one with an id of 12.

Contents of `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` folder:

```
10-amdgpu.conf  10-quirks.conf  11-evdev-quirks.conf      51-synaptics-quirks.conf  70-wacom.conf
10-evdev.conf   10-radeon.conf  11-evdev-trackpoint.conf  70-synaptics.conf
```

Contents of `70-synaptics.conf`:

```
# Example xorg.conf.d snippet that assigns the touchpad driver
# to all touchpads. See xorg.conf.d(5) for more information on
# InputClass.
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, your distribution will likely overwrite
# it when updating. Copy (and rename) this file into
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d first.
# Additional options may be added in the form of
#   Option "OptionName" "value"
#
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
# This option is recommend on all Linux systems using evdev, but cannot be
# enabled by default. See the following link for details:
# http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html
      MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad ignore duplicates"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchOS "Linux"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/mouse*"
        Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection

# This option enables the bottom right corner to be a right button on clickpads
# and the right and middle top areas to be right / middle buttons on clickpads
# with a top button area.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Default clickpad buttons"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
        Option "SecondarySoftButtonAreas" "58% 0 0 15% 42% 58% 0 15%"
EndSection

# This option disables software buttons on Apple touchpads.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Disable clickpad buttons on Apple touchpads"
        MatchProduct "Apple|bcm5974"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

Like I said, none of the solutions in the questions I looked at helped me.  I believe this is because none of them dealt with synaptics drivers (which is what I'm using).

This is the package of the driver I am using:

```
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-16.04
```

I was able to achieve (almost) what I want using the `synclient` command. Here's what I did:

1. When I ran `synclient` I saw these two settings: `VertScrollDelta = -46` and `HorizScrollDelta = -46`
2. So I used these commands to change them from negative to positive: `synclient VertScrollDelta = 46; synclient HorizScrollDelta = 46`

I have yet to reboot, so I don't know if these settings will be saved, but I will figure that out another time.

---

This reversed two-finger scroll works everywhere except in the menu.
When I use the menu in the bottom-left corner, the scrolling is not changed.

I would like to make it so it will reverse even in the menu.

---

Edit:

I had to add the commands to Startup Applications to get it to change after restart.

It also worked all of a sudden in the menu but not anywhere else.  I do not know what caused it, but after another restart it is back to the same problem.